# Booting a .net EXE file onto an X86 computer

Tags: .net, operating-system, x86

The question says it all. I am wondering If there is any way to boot a .net EXE file as an OS for X86. If there is existing software that compiles the EXE code into x86, I would appreciate hearin about it.

Thank you!

Comment: `The question says it all.` Well, not really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

.NET requires an operating system (Windows) to provide actual functionality in order to run it's applications, it's impossible for a .NET application to run as an operating system itself.